# define a failure horizon based on serial number and failure label

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wanted to re-label the healthy label (0) to failure label (1) 3 days before the actual failure (1) like what they did in the attached link: [Reference link](https://datatonic.com/insights/machine-learning-predictive-maintenance-hard-drive-failure/). It worked well for the equal time length but did not work for the variable length. That is, all serial number must fail in the same day which doesn't make sense. For the sample dataset, we see that serial C failed in January 5, 2014, A failed in January 6, and A failed in January 7. I want to relabel the re-label the healthy label (0) to failure label (1) 3 days before the actual failure (1) for the serial number C, and for the other serial numbers as well. I appreciate your time. Thanks!

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
df = pd.read_excel('/content/failure.xlsx') 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by="date")
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
a = []
for ind in df.index:
  if df['failure'][ind] == 1:
    sdate = df['date'][ind] - d
    edate = df['date'][ind]
    delta = edate - sdate 
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
      day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
      a.append(day)
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(a))
mylist = pd.to_datetime(mylist,format='%y/%m/%d')
new_value = 1
for ind in df.index:
  for item in mylist:
    if df['date'][ind].date() ==  pd.to_datetime(item).date():
       df['failure'][ind] = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution. Note: I preferred to rewrite it completely for clarity.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
df = pd.read_excel('content/failure.xlsx') 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.sort_values(by="date").reindex_like(df) # We need to rebuild the index after sorting
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 3)

failed=df[df['failure']==1] # disks that actually failed

for hdd in failed['serial_number']: # for each hdd
    ind=df.index[df['serial_number']==hdd] # look for that patricular hdd in df
    # Note: the last element of ind corresponds to the failure date for hdd
    failure_date=df.iloc[ind[-1],1] # [rows,column==1] --> (:,'date')
    for i in ind[:-1]:
        if (failure_date - df.iloc[i,1]).days <= d.days:
            df.iloc[i,3]=1 # set failure to 1
            

print('hdd: A')
print(df[df['serial_number']=='A'])

print('hdd: C')
print(df[df['serial_number']=='C'])

print('hdd: H')
print(df[df['serial_number']=='H'])
```

Resulting in:

```
hdd: A
   model       date serial_number  failure  smart5  smart187
1      M 2014-01-01             A        0       0        60
5      M 2014-01-02             A        0       0       140
7      M 2014-01-03             A        1       0       180
11     M 2014-01-04             A        1       0       260
12     M 2014-01-05             A        1       0       280
16     M 2014-01-06             A        1       0       360
hdd: C
   model       date serial_number  failure  smart5  smart187
2      M 2014-01-01             C        0       0        80
4      M 2014-01-02             C        1       0       120
8      M 2014-01-03             C        1       0       200
10     M 2014-01-04             C        1       0       240
13     M 2014-01-05             C        1       0       300
hdd: H
   model       date serial_number  failure  smart5  smart187
0      M 2014-01-01             H        0       0        40
3      M 2014-01-02             H        0       0       100
6      M 2014-01-03             H        0       0       160
9      M 2014-01-04             H        1       0       220
14     M 2014-01-05             H        1       0       320
15     M 2014-01-06             H        1       0       340
17     M 2014-01-07             H        1       0       400
```

Comment: I got this error after running the code: ---> 19         if (failure_date - df.iloc[i,1]).days <= d.days:
     20             df.iloc[i,3]=1 # set failure to 1
     21 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Could you add just before line 19: print(type(failure_date)) and report the result. It should be: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

Comment: And please, give the version of pandas you're using: in a terminal: python -c "import pandas; print(pandas.__version__)"  I use 1.3.2. And also, what version of Python do you use? (I use 3.8)

Comment: I've updated the code so that you shouldn't have that error. But, I would recommend you use recent versions of Pandas and Python.

Comment: I am using pandas version 1.1.5. I am still getting error. --> 450                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    451                 dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

Comment: Please update your pandas version: 1) pip uninstall pandas 2) pip install pandas --user Because Version 1.1.5 is old. Also, python version?

Comment: Since it doesn't help I reverted back to the original version.

Comment: Could you try my original code with this file? https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bkdx657jknfubw0olrrj7/failure_test.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=tq42qp0j422xbz2wu3e350ocx  Just in case it has to do with the file itself.

Comment: It's working! Thanks!

Comment: Good! So, what was the problem?

Comment: My data set has Unnamed: 0 index column. I deleted that column and it worked!